# How to reinstall the files of a packages

Tags: flutter, dart, package

I installed package audioplayers in my flutter project.
Then I deleted the file of it in external libraries.
So that I can reinstall it.
but after deleting files of it, My terminal shows it is already install and also pubspec file works fine.
but when trying importing it says this doesn't exist.
What can i do now ??

Answer (score 2):

Its easy to re install packages and remove them.

Use this command to delete all dependencies and clear project cavh.

```
flutter clean
```

Then this to make them again.

```
flutter pub get
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply **flutter clean** command or manually delete the build folder and then get
the packages by this command **flutter packages get** or **flutter pub get** or manually open pubspec.yaml file and press **ctrl+S**.